# Understanding OpenUI5's Controller.getView()

Tags: sapui5

According to OpenUI5 API reference Controller.getView() returns "*... the view associated with this controller or undefined.*"

Source: [API: getView()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller/methods/getView)

What I don't get: **Where becomes the controller tied together with a certain view?**

The controller don't keep an information about a view. Views on the other hand have an attribute "*controllerName*".

But **how does the controller get the information about it's associated view?** Is it done via the file-naming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller has a methode called Controller.prototype.connectToView in there the connection is made as the name suggests.

The framework calls it on its own, so the connection is made automatically.
Basically the methode creates a property inside the controller called oView in which the view is stored.

If you would call the debugger in one of your functions just switch to to console, type "this" then the console will give the controller. Press the arrow to see the controllers content and BAM you will see the property I spoke of.

[image: oView property in controller]

Answer (score 2):

The controller is tied with view via definition of controller name in the view e.g.:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="controllerName" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:suite="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
    xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data" xmlns:vbm="sap.ui.vbm" displayBlock="true"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```